# PHP mail() adding different adress for reply and reply all

Tags: php, email

I have a php mailing list in which, when someone sends an email to group email, it gets sent to all members of that group. So when James sends email to groupemail@tes.com, It gets sent to all members of group, i want members to be able to reply to James only by clicking "reply" in their email client or reply to group email by clicking "reply all" in their client. Please suggest how this can be done. IF i set group email in Cc header, the email gets sent to recipient twice, once from cc and once from reply-to. The code for header that I have right now is:

```
$headers = 'From: '. $senderName .' <'.$senderEmail.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $senderName .' <'.$senderEmail.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$groupTitle .' <'.$groupEmail.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP' . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
```

Comment: If this is a serious production environment, I highly recommend to use a mailing service such as Mailgun instead of PHP's mail function.

Comment: You're trying to build a cathedral out of matchsticks, and while impressive if it's ever completed, the amount of effort and frustration will be significant. Instead I would suggest using mailgun as recommended or a similar PHP Mailing library such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Which can handle this exact situation with ease, using a mailing loop and a keep alive tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your group distribution service the way it redirects messages so that one won't get the message from the group address if he is in the To-list. Unfortunately, this is how email clients work, so you can't change something anout it using the way you send mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can store reply all data in a array. In header portion of reply-to run a for loop to execute that data. Just formatting like single email address.